# c# datagridview in tabpanel

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tabpanel

In my form i've a tabpanel with five tab.
Every tab have a datagridview binded to a databes.
All datagrid are filled correctly,but the event `CellContentClick` works only on the frist tab.
I'm trying to retrive content on selected cell with this code:

```
//fristtabpag and datagrid1
private void dgw1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    text1.Text = dgw1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
}
//second tabpag and datagrid1
private void dgw2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    text1.Text = dgw2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
}
//other....
```

And it works only on frist tabpage.

i use same code corrrectly fixed for other page, but i get an error for the index.
How fix it?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: fixed it on question post.

Comment: _I use same code corrrectly fixed for other page_. No, probably not. Make sure you have 5 different methods each __hooked__ up to the CellContentClick  events of the 5 DGVs. Also note that the CellContentClick event does what its name says: It fires only when the __content__ not when empty parts of a cell are clicked.

Comment: same issue with cellClick.Datagridview use same database,and show only a column per page.i've retrived index,and [0] are correct.I don't understand why i get index error.

Comment: A simple provision, not a fix but a quite normal check in the spirit of defensive programming is to include a check like this: `if (SelectedRows[0].Count>0)`. But you probably wonder why it is necessary in the first place. Have you checked the DGVs for their SelectionMode property? If it isn't `CellSelect` clicking into a Cell won't select the Row!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the DataGridViewCellEventArgs like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {                       
        DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;                                   
        text1.Text = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.SafeToString();
    }
```

Alternatively you could try using the CurrentCellChanged event and get the value from the CurrentCell property:

```
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
        if (dgv.CurrentCell != null)
        {
            text1.Text = ((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell.Value.SafeToString();
        }
    }
```

(The method SafeToString() is a simple extensionmethod, all it does is check if the object is null before calling ToString(). If the object is null it returns an empty string)

From your code-example it looks like your eventhandlers does the same thing to different DataGridViews. By using the sender parameter, you can use the same handler for all the DataGridViews.